# openssl, dafault expiry validity if not provided at creation time

Tags: openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

If I create a public private key using openssl, without using any validity flags or any days flag or default days.
What will be the expiry time for such a public private key.
I believe such keys don't have any expiry time.
Please confirm.
I tried looking many Google search results but didn't find much info on this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Thanks for the info, will post such queries or discission in that.

Comment: Is there any chance to move this question into the informative security exchange so that the question and answers will continue so that our ultimate aim of knowledge sharing is still on. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure about when your keys expire, use the following command to know it:

`openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in yourfile`

EDIT: Creating a cert without -days option, it seems expiration date is 30 days after the time certificate is created.

Comment: Does that means, the keys won't have specific validity, the certificate which used to create the keys have validity.

Comment: Private keys not expire. Expiration property is used to invalidate a public key (contained in a certificate) although it could still decrypt messages.

Comment: Appreciated @AdSsa,

Comment: I created the private and public keys 4 months ago and i am still able to encrypt and decrypt data across client requests and even client can able to use his set of keys without any problem.

Comment: OP has a key, not a certificate. He would need to use `openssl rsa`,  `openssl dsa`, `openssl ec` or other subcommands; and not the  `openssl x509` subcommand.

Comment: @jww, but cert is the one which expires, isn't it?